# External Hard Disk used for Time Machine not detected on any other devices

Tags: time-machine, external-disk

I have been using a 1TB Seagate hard drive since 2017 as a Time Machine disk. I've noticed this problem since then, but the hard disk literally doesn't get detected on any other computer. I've tried it on multiple Windows computers and laptops and it just doesn't pop up.

The drive is connected, the light is on but its not detected. Its only become a problem now that I need to store things from other computers and not just my primary laptop. I attempted a partition but that took hours and didn't move forward at all, I tried first aid but that keeps failing due to an unmounting error. Please tell me someone has answers.

Comment: What macOS are you running? Also, please clarify "I attempted a partition" - where did you attempt that? On Windows or Mac? Windows cannot natively read Mac disks, so we need to know precisely what you did...

Comment: partitioning a running Backup drive is a bad idea. Also storing data on a backup drive doesn't make sense, what if the backup drive dies? Then you don't have that data saved...

Comment: Can you add to your question the results of the terminal command `diskutil list external ` from the Mac where this external drive is functional and from the other Mac?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just that Windows doesn't have a driver for that file-system format.

Also, please note that Time Machine doesn't present a **backups.backupdb** file on certain drives such as SSD's which use the APFS format.  Instead, the backup occupies its own "volume."  But a "volume" is a *logical* subdivision of the available disk space, not a *physical* one.  If you want to put other files on your backup drive, you do so by creating a new "volume."  You do not set a size for that volume – disk-space is simply allocated as needed for both the Time Machine volume and any other ones.  Use "Disk Utility" to manage the volume list.